# Reuse reset password in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to reuse the reset password in Laravel (Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails) to a form that I'm using.

**Controller**

```php
public function resetPassword($id)
{
    $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
    SendsPasswordResetEmails::sendResetLinkEmail($user->email);

    return back()->with('success', 'Password has been sent on email.');
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> Non-static method
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails::sendResetLinkEmail()
>   should not be called statically

Answer (score 1):

As error showing, you should not call static way for `sendResetLinkEmail` function. You can use below code:

```
public function resetPassword($id)
{
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $sendResetObject = new SendsPasswordResetEmails();
        $sendResetObject->sendResetLinkEmail($user->email);

        return back()->with('success', 'Password has been sent on email.');
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I've applied that but got this error `Cannot instantiate trait Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails`